# Changing SVG elements on the fly,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, svg

I have this HTML:

```
<span class="pop">
    <svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="180px" viewBox="-18.25 -18.75 200 180" enable-background="new -18.25 -18.75 200 180" xml:space="preserve">
        <text class="triangle-text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 63 -5.25)"  font-family="'HelveticaNeue'" font-size="11">text</text>
        <text class="triangle-text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 51 156.75)"  font-family="'HelveticaNeue'" font-size="11">text1</text>
        <text class="triangle-text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -13.4998 77)"  font-family="'HelveticaNeue'" font-size="11">text2</text>
        <text class="triangle-text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 126 77)" font-family="'HelveticaNeue'" font-size="11">text3</text>
        <g>
            <polygon class="sl" fill="#F4f2f3" points="" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</span>
```

Then I prepare another SVG content from js and using jquery's `replaceWith()` I replace the original SVG. It is replaced as seen in Firebug but it is not displayed in the browser.

My JS:

```
   pop = '<svg xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new -18.25 -18.75 200 180" viewBox="-18.25 -18.75 200 180" height="180px" width="200px" y="0px" x="0px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"><text haschanged="true" class="triangle-text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 63 -5.25)"  font-family="HelveticaNeue" font-size="11">Chiara</text>\n\
          <text class="triangle-text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 51 156.75)"  font-family="HelveticaNeue" font-size="11">Non chiara</text>\n\
          <text class="triangle-text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -13.4998 77)"  font-family="HelveticaNeue" font-size="11"><tspan x="10" y="10">Non</tspan><tspan x="10" y="20">concordo</tspan></text>\n\
          <text class = "triangle-text" transform = "matrix(1 0 0 1 -13.4998 77)"  font - family = "HelveticaNeue" font - size = "11" >Concordo</text>\n\
          <g>';
      for (key in triangles) {
        pop += '<polygon class = "sl" index = "' + key + '" understanding = "' + triangles[key].a + '" comprehension = "' + triangles[key].c + '" fill = "' + colors[resp.msg[key]] + '" points = "' + triangles[key].points + '" msg = "' + triangles[key].msg + '" />';
      }
      pop += '</g></svg>';
```

I do my binding like this:

```
$('.pop').children('svg').replaceWith(pop);
```

I have gone through questions on the forum related to this but did not find a solution.

Comment: `style="display: none"`?

Comment: that is removed as i replace the content with jquery.

Comment: Can you show your JS code?

Comment: Works fine for me. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3CQmn/

Answer (score 0):

Try this after the replace:

```
$('.pop').html($('pop').html());
```

Comment: Nopes..NOt working..It replaces the html but browser dosen't render it

Comment: @SankalpMishra: and refreshing the body? `$('body').html($('body').html());`. Also, can you add the Jquery code to your question?

Comment: actually this code is used to prepare a pop up on mouse over. After refreshing everything is fine..but if i change the html and mouse over it shows the same pop

Comment: Is this related to events? Are you binding the old SVG content to the event or are you getting the new content when the event occures?

Comment: @SankalpMishra: this seems to be a problem with binding events, you need to unbind and bind again with the new SVG content, maybe if you add some relevant Jquery code?

Comment: @DrColossos I just replace the old svg content with new one on click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your problem is the way you are creating the SVG fragment.  You can't use jQuery like that to create SVGs the same way you create HTML fragments.  jQuery won't create the SVG in the right namespace.

You will need to either create the SVG manually DOM element-by-DOM element.  Or use a plugin such as jQuery SVG or d3.js.